# JQuery Append Tables

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, append, dynamic-tables

I'm trying to create dynamic tables in my registration page and I've given up on using plugins and am just gonna use this append thing. I want the table to show up **ONLY** if the user selects a certain option. So here's my html:

```
<div id="Reg_num2" style="display:none;" >
    <button id="AddLine">Add Line</button>
    <table border="1px" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Ethnicity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
            <td><input type=text /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>​
</div>
```

And here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("input[name= 'Reg_num_r']").change( function () {
        if($(this).val()==1) {
            $("#Reg_num2").hide();
        } else {
            $("#Reg_num2").show();
        }
    });

    $("#table").on("click", "button", function() {
       $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
    });​

    $("#AddLine").click(function () {
        var row = "<tr><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td>                   <input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><button>X</button></td></tr>";
        $("#table").append(row);
    });
});
```

There are two problems I am having:

1. The table won't show when the user selects the appropriate radio button. What's wrong with the code?
2. When I click the add button, it submits the entire page instead, how do I fix that?

Comment: There is no element with `Reg_num_r` name attribute and also radio input in your markup, can you provide a [jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Richard Have you tried scape type=text with type='text'??? And please push f12 and tell us what console error appear after select the option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"2) When I click the add button, it submits the entire page instead, how do i fix that?"*

A `<button>` element with no `type` attribute specified will be `type="submit"` by default, so if it's in a form it will submit the form. Change it to `<button type="button">`.

I'm not sure about your radio button problem, though I'd be inclined to use `.click` rather than `.change` - please update your question to show the associated html.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
if($(this).val()==1) {
```

Should be

```
if($(this).val()=="1") {
```

The second answere

```
$("#submitButton").submit(function(){
//do things
return false;
});
```

Comment: `"1"==1` will be `true`, won't it? (As compared to "1"===1 which will be `false`.)

Comment: @AlbertoLeón Tried that and it didn't work. The weird thing is this code actually worked before adding all this table business in. I don't understand what could possibly have happened with adding table code.

Comment: @nnnnnn val() always returns a string, so 1 is a int the should be false, not true.

Comment: If you compare a string to a number with the double-equals operator it will coerce the string to a number. If you compare with the triple-equals operator it doesn't coerce.